# How to remove lines that doesnot contain specific string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi am trying to remove the lines that donot contain specific string
Suppose am having lines

```
<p>hello are news watch</p>
<p>news watch</p>
<p>news watch hour</p>
<p>hey how</p>
<p>hey news</p>
```

My specific string is news watch

How can I remove the lines that contain word news watch

Expected output is:

```
 hello are news watch
 news watch
 news watch hour
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up the string using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), then filter out lines containing the text using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) methods and finally join back them using [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

```js
var str = `hello are news watch
news watch
news watch hour
hey how
hey news`;

console.log(
  str.split('\n')
  .filter(function(v) {
    return v.indexOf('news watch') > -1;
  })
  .join('\n')
)
```

---

In case they are p tags and you want to remove those then use jQuery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method.

```js
/*
$('body').html($('body p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('news watch') > -1;
}))
*/


$('body p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('news watch') === -1;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello are news watch</p>
<p> news watch</p>
<p> news watch hour</p>
<p> hey how</p>
<p> hey news</p>
```

---

In case you need to get those text then use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) method.

```js
console.log(
  $('body p').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('news watch') > -1 ? $(this).text() : null;
  }).get().join('\n')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello are news watch</p>
<p> news watch</p>
<p> news watch hour</p>
<p> hey how</p>
<p> hey news</p>
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan How ca I do case insensitive in this

Comment: @babukumar : convert both into lowercase while comparing

Comment: @babukumar `return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('news watch') === -1;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter as mentioned in the earlier post or you can use regular expressions.To do this in php you would split it into an array of lines and then use preg_grep. Most high level languages will have support for regular expressions.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_grep.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").each(function(){
 var str=$(this).text();  
 if (str.indexOf("news watch") <= 0)
 {
  $(this).hide(); // or use remove();
 }
});
```